# trying to get method to work

Tags: java

I have a project and I need to get a method to work. I am not sure where it is messing up but I also need to add a loop to the method to allow only 3 attempts for input or terminate. If its blank 3 times the program should terminate. Does this need to be a while loop?

I'm having a hard time picking up on this.

```
private static String getStringInput(String prompt) {

    // declare variables
    String openingMsg, nameInputMsg, customerName, nameOutputMsg, 
           returnInputMsg, customerReturn, returnOutputMsg, colorInputMsg, colorSelection, 
           greetingOutputMsg, outputMsg;

    // display opening message
    openingMsg = "*** Welcome to Pizzas-R-Us Online Ordering System ***\n"
               + "                     It's a great day to order a pizza!";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, openingMsg);


    // get required input using dialogs
    nameInputMsg   = "Please enter your name: ";
    customerName   = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(nameInputMsg);



    returnInputMsg = "Are you a returning customer (yes or no)? ";
    customerReturn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(returnInputMsg);

    if (customerReturn.equals("yes"))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thanks for coming back!");
    }

    else if (customerReturn.equals("no"))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thanks for being New!");
    }

    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Syntax");
    }

    colorInputMsg = "What color would you like (black, silver, gold)";
    colorSelection  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(colorInputMsg);

    private static double totalCost(int number, double cost, double salesTaxRate)


    // build output strings
    nameOutputMsg     = "Welcome " + customerName + ".\n\n";
    returnOutputMsg   = "Your return customer status is " + customerReturn + ".\n"; 
    colorOutputMsg = "you have selected a " + colorSelection + " watch .\n;
    greetingOutputMsg = "Thank you for visiting Pizzas-R-Us!" + "\n\n"
                      + "Your order should be ready in less than 10 minutes.\n";


    // create and display output string
    outputMsg = nameOutputMsg + returnOutputMsg + colorOutputMsg + greetingOutputMsg;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputMsg);

    System.exit(0);
} // end main()


public static String getStringInput(String prompt)
{
    String inputValue;

    do
    {
        inputValue - jOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt);
        if (inputValue == null)
        {
            jOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have canceled the program");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        if (inputValue.equals(""))
        {
            jOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "no input received")
        }

        return inputValue;

    } while(inputValue.equals("" && ));
}

    public static double totalCost(int number, double cost, double salesTaxRate){
}
```

Comment: he is already using go-while loop :) `jOptionPane` should be `JOptionPane`

Comment: If using an IDE, then the multiple errors will be highlighted. If it is homework however, and it specifies not to use an IDE, then you're expected to find these on your own and you'll have to rely on reading the errors when you try to compile

Comment: your `while(inputValue.equals("" && ));` is missing a value after `&&`...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible there are other problems with your code, I don't know what kind of exceptions you were getting or if it would even compile, but here is a way to implement the loop to try to get input 3 times and quite if they keep not entering anything:

```
public static String getStringInput(String prompt) {

    String inputValue;
    int counter = 0;  // introduce counter to track times no input received

    do {
        inputValue = jOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt);
        if (inputValue == null) {
            jOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have canceled the program");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        if (inputValue.equals("")) {
            jOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "no input received")
            counter++;  // increment the counter
        }
    } while(inputValue.equals("") && counter < 3); // add condition to also exit loop if no input received 3 times

    return inputValue; // moved return outside of loop
}
```